# Using preconnect resource hint from the main window to improve the performance of a script inside a foreign iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, prefetch, web-performance

I have a website that have a **foreign iframe**. There are multiple third party scripts that run inside this foreign iframe.

I know that if I will `prefetch` these scripts from the main window - the iframe will need to reload these sources (as the `prefetch` was done in a different domain).

What can be the **reason** that if I add `dns-prefetch` or `preconnect` resource hints for the third party scripts in the main window, the performance of loading these scripts in the iframe will be improved? Is this just because I warm-up the scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers implement a [double-keyed HTTP Cache](https://andydavies.me/blog/2018/09/06/safari-caching-and-3rd-party-resources/) for privacy reasons to prevent tracking. This means if domain1 loads jQuery from a CDN and then domain2 loads the same jQuery resource from the same domain it will be downloaded again rather than reusing the same copy from the HTTP cache.

Safari has done this for a while and [Chrome have recently stated they will do the same](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/blink-dev/bSMOY-evrV4).

This means you can’t `prefetch` or `preload` resources and scripts in foreign domain iframes as you state.

`dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` have no such privacy implications (for now - see [Andy's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446485/using-preconnect-resource-hint-from-the-main-window-to-improve-the-performance-o/59633561#59633561) for potential upcoming changes for preconnect). so they can be used to improve performance in iframes by front loading some of the work to get these scripts (though it should be noted that browsers [may not always use the same connection depending on the browser](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/#multiple-pages-can-use-the-same-http2-connection) which may impact use of `preconnect`).

Comment: Thanks a lot @barry-pollard! Your answer helped me to dig into this and to find this document: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bKGDIePAuF6YXmmrwM33LeLvtuCsla3vTspsxsNp-f8/edit)

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that connection pools are also going to become double keyed too –https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/917

In this scenario `dns-prefetch` will be ok, but a `preconnect` from the top frame origin for resources referenced in the iframe won't as top frame origin will be different to the iframe origin

Contents of the iframe should still be able to make their own preconnects though – using either link element or HTTP header

(Added as new answer as comments can't have line breaks)